# regexp php, I need to replace all the words of the template

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace all the words of the template, but these words enclosed in {} and []. Please help

```
$content = '<div class="header header">{header} {header2} [header][/header]</div>';
$content = preg_replace("/(\s|\"|\')(^$)header(^$)(\s|\"|\')/is",'new_class',$content);
```

**OUTPUT** should be the following: `<div class="new_class new_class">{header} {header2} [header][/header]</div>`

Comment: Could you post what the desired output should be? The "all the words" kind of foggy for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$content = '<div class="header header">{header} {header2} [header][/header]</div>';
$content = preg_replace("/([\\s\"'])header(?=[\\s\"'])/is",'$1new_class',$content);
```

This replaces all "header" surrounded by either `"'` or white space.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, the double backslashes threw off my Python (it should be `\s`, not `\\s`, but in PHP, there are some very weird escaping rules within strings...)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace('/header(?![^{}[\]]*[\]}])/', 'new_class', $subject);
```

replaces `header` with `new_class` only if the next following bracket or brace is not a closing bracket or brace.

Comment: Thank you very much for a long time I have with this tormented